Lower bound on the number of transitive sub-tournaments of size k in a tournament of size N.
Given a tournament of size $N$, what are the lower bounds on the number of transitive sub-tournaments of size $k$? What about specific values of $k$? For $k = 3$ I know the number of transitive sub-tournaments is
$$
T_3 = \frac{N(N-1)(N-3)}{8} + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^N d_i^2
$$
Where $d_i$ is the difference between the in-degree and out-degree of vertex $i$. One can then argue about what values each $d_i$ can take on based on whether $N$ is even or odd. Are there any other tight bounds like this for $k>3$?

A trivial lower bound is that, for $n\ge2^{k-1}$, a tournament of order $n$ has at least $\binom nk/\binom{2^{k-1}k$ transitive subtournaments of order $k$. I don't know anything nontrivial.

Theorem 12 of Moon's Topics on Tournaments provides a lower bound for the number of transitive subtournaments of order $k$ in a tournament of order $n$.

In Topics on Tournaments by John W. Moon, $T_n$ denotes a tournament of order $n$. Quoting from pp. 22–23:

Let $r(n,k)$ denote the minimum number of transitive subtournaments $T_k$ a tournament $T_n$ can have. It follows from Theorem 10 that $r(n,k)=0$ if $k\gt[2\log_2n]+1$ and $r(k,n)\gt0$ if $k\le[\log_2n]+1$.
THEOREM $12$. Let
$$\tau(n,k)=\begin{cases}
n\cdot\frac{(n-1)}2\cdot\frac{(n-3)}4\dots\frac{(n-2^{k-1}+1)}{2^{k-1}}\text{ if }n\gt2^{k-1}-1,\\
0\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{ if }n\le2^{k-1}-1.\\
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$r(n,k)\ge\tau(n,k).$$

